# Eloquent where clause on belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Lets say I have already loaded the relationship and now I want to get models that fulfill it.
Is there a way to do it in an objective way, rather than using ids directly?
Here is an example Controller describing what I want to achieve:

```
public function videos(User $user, Category $category)
{
    $videos = Video::where('user', $user)->where('category', $category)->get();
    // ...
}
```

I know I can do it like this, but I would like to skip extracting the id and leave it to the framework if possible:

```
public function videos(User $user, Category $category)
{
    $videos = Video::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('category_id', $category->id)->get();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is just for knowledge and cleaner code?

Comment: In `where('table_column', $value)` or `where(['table_column' => $value])` you can see what Eloquent Builder is looking for. Responsible code is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L220). Although I don't see the gain in what you would like to do, you could write some kind of wrapper that overwrite default `where` method behavior - NOT recommended at all because you could loose more then get.

Comment: Or another thing, you could write custom method in Video model that returns what you need there: `$userVideosOfCategory = Video::userVideoOfCategory(User $user, Category $category);` and logic you make in custom Video model's method. Logic could be kind of similar to policies/gate.

Comment: This is mostly for cleaner code.  
And to avoid implementation leaking outside.   
Less things in the public API the more I can change later without risking compatibility issues.
Also just to be clear, I don't need to stick with the `where` method. 
As long as I just need to provide relationship name and object, then I will be happy, even if its a separate method eg. `whereRelated('user', $user)`

Answer (score 0):

So you would have a video that belongs to a user, correct? You could do something a little like this:

In your User model:

```
public function videos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
}
```

And then you can call this funciton like

```
$user->videos();
```

or

```
$this->user->videos->toArray();
```

If you start creating relationships like this in the model, it can make retrieving data so much easier. Might not be the full answer but is definitely on the right track. Good luck!

Eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: That works with single relationship and that is how I was doing it for some time, but now I got into a use case where I need to check 2 relationships and there might be more in the future as my class will be getting more complex.

Comment: You might want to check out 'has many through' - does this seem like the kind of relationship that you will be forming? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect, but I found a way to do it easily using scopes.
Here is my code:

```
trait WhereBelongsTo
{
    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|self $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|self
     */
    public function scopeWhereBelongsTo($query, $relationship, $value)
    {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo $relationship */
        $relationship = call_user_func([$this, $relationship]);

        $foreignKey = $relationship->getForeignKey();
        $ownerKey = $relationship->getOwnerKey();

        if($value === null) {
            return $query->whereNull($foreignKey);
        } else {
            return $query->where($foreignKey, $value->$ownerKey);
        }
    }
}
```

After adding this trait to a Model, I can use it like this:

```
public function videos(User $user, Category $category)
{
    $videos = Video::whereBelongsTo('user', $user)->whereBelongsTo('category', $category)->get();
    // ...
}
```